# How to add, rotate and drag line in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What would be the best way in accomplishing this? Let's say I have a method (not defined) that would allow a line with a fixed size and color to be drawn on the screen. This line would need to then accept rotate gestures and panning gestures in order to move around the screen. It won't resize, it only needs to rotate and translate.

What is the best way of going about this? Should lines be subviews or sublayers to parent view? What is the method for drawing a line in ios? How to handle multiple lines on screen? I just want someone to lead me down the right path in the ios graphics jungle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to consider how complex the whole drawing is. From your description it sounds like the task is relatively simple. If that is the case, then Core Graphics would be the way to go. If the drawing is significantly more complex, you should look at OpenGL ES and GLKit, though using OGL involves a fair bit more work

Assuming Core Graphics, I'd store the centre point, angle and length of the line, and change the angle and size using the gesture recognizers, and calculate the points to draw using basic trig. Loop over the points to draw in the view `-drawRect` method and draw each one with the appropriate CG functions - call `[view setNeedsDisplay]` or `[view setNeedsDisplayInRect:areaToRedraw]`to trigger the redraws. (The second method only redraws the part of the view you specify, and can be used to improved performance).

The first of a series of tutorials on Core Graphics is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients).- the part on 'drawing lines' will be most relevant. I haven't done this one (I used [the old edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430236051) of [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14/276-0850059-7547526?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=beginning%20ios%206%20development%20exploring%20the%20ios%20sdk)), but I've followed a lot of others from this site and found them very helpful

As a side note you'll probably need a way to focus on a particular line if you have more than one on the screen- an easy way would be to find the line centre point closest to the point the user touched.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the best API for drawing lines like you want is with Core Graphics. Put this code within your UIView's drawRect method:

```
/* Set the color that we want to use to draw the line */ 
[[UIColor redColor] set];
/* Get the current graphics context */ 
CGContextRef currentContext =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
/* Set the width for the line */
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext,5.0f);
/* Start the line at this point */ 
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext,50.0f, 10.0f);
/* And end it at this point */ 
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext,100.0f, 200.0f);
/* Use the context's current color to draw the line */
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
```

For the gesture recognition, use [UIGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use the following methods

```
- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```